# What is the workflow for updating a rails app in AWS EC2 via Docker with docker-machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm new to Docker, and am trying to understand the workflow for **updating** my app in AWS, after it's live. For now, the rails app and MySQL database are both on the same EC2 instance. Here's what I'm doing to get the app live:

I have a dockerfile a docker-compose.yml file that define the services. The rails application source is linked to the app container with a bind mount in docker-compose.yml:

```
  app:
    ...
    volumes:
      - $PWD:/zhxword
```

When I'm ready to deploy, I run:

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-instance-type "t2.micro" production
docker-machine env production
eval $(docker-machine env production)
```

From this point on, my docker-compose commands target the production container (EC2):

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

The `docker-compose build` command took a really long time, but eventually it finished, and the app started, and I could access it over HTTP.

My question is about the process for making changes. For example, a change to docker-compose.yml (such as exposing port 443) or routine changes to the rails code. If I run `docker-compose down && docker-compose up` that doesn't seem to be enough - changes to docker-compose.yml don't seem to be reflected. I assume running `docker-compose build` is going to work, but that re-provisions the whole server, and takes an excruciatingly long time.

What are the practical steps for routine updates once the dockerized app is live? Is there a quick way of forcing it to refresh code?

Comment: You have to create a new docker image to refresh the code, and for all that aws has ECS and ECR to handle that.

Comment: You mean re-run `docker-compose build`, correct? I was hoping to avoid that because it's so slow. Is `docker-compose scp` considered too hacky? I should add that I'm trying to run everything I need on a free-tier t2.micro EC2 instance, or failing that, a slightly larger instance. I'm trying to avoid an expensive setup for the time being.