# How can I speed-up building a docker image on EC2

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm currently deploying a Rails app to a single EC2 instance. I'm new to Docker, so I could be missing something obvious. I have 2 Dockerfiles - app (Rails app) and web (nginx):

```
docker
├── app
│   └── Dockerfile
└── web
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── nginx.conf
```

docker/app/Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.8
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y \
curl \
vim \
netcat \
less \
default-mysql-client \
--no-install-recommends && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-i", "-c"]
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
RUN source /root/.bashrc && nvm install 10.19.0
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]
RUN npm install -g yarn
RUN yarn install --check-files
RUN mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/zhxword
ENV RAILS_ROOT /home/ubuntu/zhxword
EXPOSE 3000
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT
ADD Gemfile $RAILS_ROOT/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock $RAILS_ROOT/Gemfile.lock
ADD . $RAILS_ROOT
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install
RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

docker/web/Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y install apache2-utils
ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/app_name
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT
RUN mkdir log
COPY public public/
COPY docker/web/nginx.conf /tmp/docker.nginx
RUN envsubst '$RAILS_ROOT' < /tmp/docker.nginx > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

The MySQL server is brought in via docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1'

volumes:
  db_data: {}

# This part is explained below the file
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci --init-connect='SET NAMES UTF8;' --innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=0
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: XXXXXX
      MYSQL_DATABASE: zhxword_production
      MYSQL_USER: zhxword
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: XXXXXX
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/app/Dockerfile
    command: /bin/sh -c "bin/wait-for db:3306 -- rm -f /home/ubuntu/zhxword/tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails server puma -p 3000"
    volumes:
      - $PWD:/zhxword
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - "db:database"
    env_file:
      - .env.production
    depends_on:
      - db
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/web/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

I am using `docker-machine` to publish to AWS:

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-instance-type "t2.micro" production
docker-machine env production
eval $(docker-machine env production)
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

**THE PROBLEM**

Running `docker-compose build` against the AWS target takes about 1 hour 20 minutes.

I've tried both `t2.micro` and `t2.medium` instance types, and it seems to take the same amount of time. One of the steps in the app container that's particularly slow is *installing sassc 2.3.0 with native extensions*, but in general both the app and web containers take a long time.

Running `docker-compose build` locally (on my laptop) is much faster - about 7 minutes total. Running `docker-compose up` only takes a minute or two against the AWS target.

What strategies can I employ to speed up the build process?

Answer (score 2):

1. I really suggest reading the following page `https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/`
2. Read about multistage build and it might help with making your builds faster

from a glance at your rails docker file i see a lot of bad usage of the RUN instruction. this creates redundant layers. 
you are basing your rails application on a big image, try searching for a slimmer image like `2.7.1-alpine3.11`.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding the last point, you're suggesting switching the **app** image from ruby:2.5.8 -> 2.7.1-alpine3.11? I'll definitely read into the more involved changes, but that seems like a thing I can try quickly.

Comment: @antun if your base image is slim is will reduce the build time significantly, alpine is much slimmer than the regular base image will contains alot of OS modules that you probably don't need

Comment: @antun you want to your docker containers to be as small and as compact as possible, what i mean by that is that the smaller the container is and it has the minimal requirements to make your application run, you will get the advantage of faster builds faster uploads and better security and faster time for the application to load when the container starts

Comment: I understand, but all the guides on running Rails in Docker that I've seen use the **ruby** image. (Including the official Docker guide one: https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/). If I start with a lighter image, I'm going to have to add dependencies so the Rails app will run, right? It seems the ruby image is based on buildpack-deps, which is an official Docker image - would that be considered a "heavy" one?

Comment: @antun, the guides that you find online are probably not the best, i am working with node.JS and it took time for me to find the best practices online for how to create the best dockerfiles. and YES it is much better starting with a slimmer base image and installing whatever you need on top of it. it will still be lighter.

Answer (score 1):

You should build your image locally, push it to a Docker registry (in an AWS context, consider ECR), and then run the image from the EC2 instance.

In your `docker-compose.yml` file the important thing you need to do locally is add `image:` lines for the two images you're building that reference your (ECR) external repository.  Locally you can continue to `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` the same way you are now.

The `app` container has a bind mount that will not work on the remote EC2 instance (unless you separately copy your application there, which defeats one of the reasons to use Docker).  Delete the `volumes:` there.  Make sure your application still works as expected (locally).

Now you can `docker-compose push` your built images.  Delete the `build:` blocks from the `docker-compose.yml` file, and run it in the same way you are now.

There are two reasons I can immediately think of that your build would be slow.  `docker build` starts by taking the local directory tree (the build context) and sending it across the Docker socket to the daemon; this will be much faster on a local system than a remote.  The second is that the `t2` shared instances and especially a `t2.micro` are underpowered for many applications, so if your `yarn install` or your Rails precompile step do a significant amount of work, those could just take a lot longer on that minimal instance type.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I'll explore the approach of preparing the image locally and pushing to a registry. Regarding the bind mount for the application source, I have another question on SO about whether I'm following the correct process for updating the app: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62240806/what-is-the-workflow-for-updating-a-rails-app-in-aws-ec2-via-docker-with-docker . Right now, I have to rebuild every time I make a change to the code. If not a bind mount, what is the correct way to link the app source code?

Comment: Develop your application locally, and rebuild the image on every change.  Doubly true if you're deploying it remotely: if you run Docker locally with an image but with all of the interesting parts replaced with your local source tree, you're never actually testing the `docker build` image and your remote deployment is running untested code.

Comment: I understand. But when I do the `docker build` step locally, it takes ~7 minutes every time. I can't possibly wait 7 minutes after each code change.

Comment: I've been trying the strategy of creating an image locally and pushing it to the registry (ECR). It's still in progress, but it doesn't appear to save time. Specifically I did: 1) Created a registry in ECR; 2) Build the image locally with `docker build -f docker/app/Dockerfile -t zhxw-repo .` - this part still takes 7-8 mins locally; 3) Push the image up to ECR with `docker push XXXXX.amazonaws.com/zhxw-repo:latest` - this takes at least 30-40 mins - it uploads 2+GB. I still need to _use_ the image in the docker-compose file, so I'll see how long that takes.

Comment: Finally figured it out - posted an answer with my notes. I wouldn't have had this problem if I had been doing what you recommended from the start :) ("Develop your application locally, and rebuild the image on every change.")

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause of the slow build process, after trying a bunch of different approaches. Posting it here in case anyone else runs into it.

My app was a Rails 6 app, and Rails 6 uses Webpacker as the JavaScript compiler. Originally, I was developing on my host laptop. During development, Webpacker creates a *lot* of temporary JS files in `public/packs`, which it doesn't prune automatically. I discovered this by running the following in my host laptop:

```
$ du -skh *
4.0K    Gemfile
8.0K    Gemfile.lock
4.0K    README.md
4.0K    Rakefile
348K    app
4.0K    babel.config.js
 36K    bin
4.0K    commit_message
148K    config
4.0K    config.ru
 28K    db
 24K    docker
4.0K    docker-compose.yml
  0B    lib
3.1M    log
8.0K    misc
101M    node_modules
4.0K    package.json
4.0K    postcss.config.js
136K    public
  0B    storage
 18M    tmp
  0B    vendor
256K    yarn-error.log
240K    yarn.lock
```

In my case it was 1.2GB of content, that wasn't needed, since in production the JS files are precompiled with the `RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile` instruction. (Note: You can force Webpacker to manually clear these temporary files by running `bundle exec rails webpacker:clobber`.)

The `ADD . $RAILS_ROOT` command in `app/Dockerfile` was putting **all** of this into the remote container - that's why it was so slow.

To fix this, I added the following two lines to `.dockerignore`:

```
node_modules/*
public/packs/*
```

That tells docker to ignore these paths when it performs the `ADD` command.

With these changes the `docker-compose build` step (when targeting the remote AWS instance with `docker-machine` took only 51 seconds - down from about 1 hour 20 mins!